# Как вывести возрастающую последовательность чисел массива?

Tags: java, массивы, вывод

Есть массив чисел. Нужно вывести возрастающие последовательности.

```
int [] array = new int {2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7};
 for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i - 1]) {
            System.out.print(array[i - 1]);
        }

 }
```

В моём случае выводит 1215. Как сделать, чтобы выводились 123
                                                          157  ?

Comment: (2,3,5,7) тоже возрастает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уточнил ответ, в первом if должно быть `<=`, а не `<`

```java
int[] array = { -1, -2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7, 0, -1, 1, 7, 5, 7, 6 };
boolean newSeq = true;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] <= array[i - 1]) {
        newSeq = true;
    } else if (array[i] > array[i - 1] && newSeq) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i - 1] + "," + array[i]);
        newSeq = false;
    } else if (array[i] > array[i - 1] && !newSeq) {
        System.out.print("," + array[i]);
    }
}
```